# How can I change a value in php mysql database after a period of time?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am working on a marketplace website having database in php mysql. In the website I want to mark an order made by user as complete after 3 days. Any order's **status** value should be changed to **complete** after 3 days. Order status in database should be changed automatically after 3 days. Is there any way to achieve such goals?

Is there any way to achieve such goals?

Comment: You can make a cron job for that :)

Comment: You can use a mysql event : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/

Comment: Your SQL query that show if an order is complete or not should display only order with order timestamp < now() + 3 days

Comment: Ok thanks MySQL Scheduled Event is the way to do it ...

Answer (score 0):

First, you want a query that will does the update, 3 days or more old and status different of `'complete'`

```
UPDATE `order`
SET `order`.`status` = 'complete'
WHERE `order`.`status` <> 'complete'
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF('DAY', `order`.`date`, now()) >= 3;
```

Now, you can schedule this query to be performed every days using an event

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `update_status_event`
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 19 DAY_HOUR
    COMMENT 'Update the status every days at 19:00'
    DO
        UPDATE `order`
        SET `order`.`status` = 'complete'
        WHERE `order`.`status` <> 'complete'
        AND TIMESTAMPDIFF('DAY', `order`.`date`, now()) >= 3;
```